# rxjs check if stream is empty before handling data

Tags: javascript, rxjs

We have the following stream.

```
const recorders = imongo.listCollections('recorders')
    .flatMapConcat(names => {
        const recorders = names
            .map(entry => entry.name)
            .filter(entry => !_.contains(
                ['recorders.starts',
                 'recorders.sources',
                 'system.indexes',
                 'system.users'],
                entry));
        console.log(recorders);
        return Rx.Observable.fromArray(recorders);
    });

recorders.isEmpty()
    .subscribe(
        empty => {
            if(empty) {
                logger.warn('No recorders found.');
            }
        },
        () => {}
    );

recorders.flatMapConcat(createRecorderIntervals)
    .finally(() => process.exit(0))
    .subscribe(
        () => {},
        e => logger.error('Error while updating: %s', e, {}),
        () => logger.info('Finished syncing all recorders')
    );
```

If the stream is empty then we don't want to `createRecorderIntervals`. The above piece of code is working. However, checking if the stream is empty, is causing the `console.log` to be executed twice. Why is this happening? Can I fix it somehow?

EDIT: So, I went the following way, after rethinking it thanks to @Martin's answer

```
const recorders = imongo.listCollections('recorders')
    .flatMapConcat(names => {
        const recorders = names
            .map(entry => entry.name)
            .filter(entry => !_.contains(
                ['recorders.starts',
                 'recorders.sources',
                 'system.indexes',
                 'system.users'],
                entry));

        if(!recorders.length) {
            logger.warn('No recorders found.');
            return Rx.Observable.empty();
        }

        return Rx.Observable.fromArray(recorders);
    })
    .flatMapConcat(createRecorderIntervals)
    .finally(() => scheduleNextRun())
    .subscribe(
        () => {},
        e => logger.error('Error while updating: %s', e, {}),
        () => logger.info('Finished syncing all recorders')
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `subscribe()` method on an `Observable` it causes the entire chain of operators to be created which it turn calls `imongo.listCollections('recorders')` twice in your case.

You can insert an operator before calling `flatMapConcat(createRecorderIntervals)` that checks whether the result is empty. I have one of them in mind particularly but there might be other that suit your needs even better:

- [`takeWhile()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeWhile) - takes predicate as an argument and emits `onComplete` when it return `false`.

Then your code would be like the following:

```
const recorders = imongo.listCollections('recorders')
    .flatMapConcat(names => {
        ...
        return Rx.Observable.fromArray(recorders);
    })
    .takeWhile(function(result) {
        // condition
    })
    .flatMapConcat(createRecorderIntervals)
        .finally(() => process.exit(0))
        .subscribe(...);
```

I don't know what exactly your code does but I hope you get the idea.

Edit: If you want to be notified when the entire Observable is empty than there're a multiple of ways:

- [`do()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do) operator and a custom [Observer](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObserverDoc.html) object. You'll write a custom Observer and put it using `do()` operator before `.flatMapConcat(createRecorderIntervals)` . This object will count how many times its `next` callback was called and when the preceding Observable completes you can tell whether there was at least one or there were no results at all.
- create a [`ConnectableObservable`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/connect.html). This one is maybe the most similar to what you we're doing at the beginning. You'll turn your `recorders` into `ConnectableObservable` using `publish()` operator. Then you can subscribe multiple Observers without triggering the operator chain. When you have all your Observers subscribed you call `connect()` and it'll sequentially emit values to all Observers:

  ```
  var published = recorders.publish();

  published.subscribe(createObserver('SourceA'));
  published.subscribe(createObserver('SourceB'));

  // Connect the source
  var connection = published.connect();
  ```

  In your case, you'd create two `Subjects` (because they act as Observable and Observer at the same time) and chain one of them with `isEmpty()` and the second one with `flatMapConcat()`. See the doc for more info: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/connect.html

I think the first option is actually easier for you.

Comment: in this case I cannot check whether the whole stream is empty, since I don't get the whole array but separate values, right?

Comment: I just want to be able to show a message when there are no recorders

Comment: I updated my answer. tl;dr have a look at [`do()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do) operator.

Comment: I didn't use your suggestion but your answer helped me a lot. I edited my question to provide the solution.